# Undefined offset: 0 Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, offset

entiendo el problema pero no detecto su origen. Tengo un controlador que envía a una vista el usuario:

```
$usuario = Auth::user()->id;
        /* dd($usuario); */
        return view('SitioWeb.panel.panel', [
            'usuario' => $usuario
        ]);
```

En la vista trabajo con múltiples vistas de Livewire enviando esa variable:

```
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
        @livewire('panel.mis-propiedades-component', ['usuarioid' => $usuario])
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane fade bg-white" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">               
        @livewire('panel.mis-contactos-component', ['usuarioid' => $usuario])   
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane fade bg-white" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">   
        @livewire('panel.mis-zooms-component', ['usuarioid' => $usuario])   
  </div>
```

Si comento dos de los componentes uno sólo funciona bien, ahora el usuario siempre va a tener un valor o eso creo entender.

Si alguién quiere ver las vistas, son similares todas:

```
<div>
      @if($resultado === 0)
        <p class="text-center py-3">¡Aún no recibió contactos!</p>
      @else

        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead class="bg-white">
                <tr>
                <th scope="col">N°</th>
                <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                <th scope="col">Teléfono</th>
                <th scope="col">Correo</th>
                <th scope="col">Mensaje</th>
                <th scope="col">Propiedad</th>
                <th scope="col">Tiempo</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
                <?php $counter=1;?>
            @foreach($contactos as $contacto)
            @foreach($contacto->contactos as $valor)
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="row"> <small> <?php echo $counter;?> </small></th>
                    <td> <small> {{ $valor->nombre }} </small></td>
                    <td> <small> {{ $valor->telefono }} </small></td>
                    <td> <small> {{ $valor->email }} </small></td>
                    <td class="text-justify"> <small> {{ $valor->mensaje }} </small></td>
                    <td> <a href="{{ url('detalle-propiedad/'.$contacto->slug_propiedad) }}" class="badge badge-primary">Ver propiedad</a> </td>

                    <td style="width: 12% !important"> <small>
                        <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-clock" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 0 8 1a7 7 0 0 0 0 14zm8-7A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0z"/>
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.5 3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v5.21l3.248 1.856a.5.5 0 0 1-.496.868l-3.5-2A.5.5 0 0 1 7 9V3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
                        </svg>
                        {{ $valor->created_at->diffForHumans() }} </small>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <?php $counter++;?>
            @endforeach
            @endforeach
            </table>
        </div>
    @endif

</div>
```

**EDICIÓN**

Identifique que a las vistas Livewire había agregado un verificador para mostrar si no vienen datos un mensaje que no hay datos.

```
$resultado = $zooms[0]['zoom']->count();
'resultado' => $resultado
```

Y en las vistas:

```
@if($resultado === 0)
      <p class="text-center py-3">¡Aún no recibió contactos por Zoom!</p>
@else
```

Mi pregunta cambia a como se debe realizar la verificación? por que probé diversas formas y no logro la validación.

Comment: Podrías poner el error y la descripción del mismo? Usualmente siempre te muestra la linea o archivo en donde tienes ese error

Comment: Buenas! si encontré la linea que me genera el problema. En el componente hago lo siguiente $resultado = $zooms[0]['zoom']->count(); justamente para ver si está vacio y es lo que me da el error. Sabés como puedo verificar si está vacío así muestro un mensaje? edito la pregunta.

Comment: @maraet si le haces un `dd` a esto: `$resultado` ¿qué obtienes?

Comment: Me está pasando que recibo el error offset 0. Sólo esta linea $resultado = $zooms[0]['zoom']->count(); por más que no pase la variable $resultado a la vista recibo el error. En el dd lo mismo. no entiendo por que.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes prevenir el error de "undefined index" con un bloque como el siguiente:

```
$resultado = 0;
if (isset($zooms[0])
    && isset($zooms[0]['zoom']) {
    $resultado = $zooms[0]['zoom']->count();
}
```

Donde, en primer lugar se le asigna un valor por defecto a la variable `$resultado` para poder usarla más adelante si `$zooms` no tuviera lo esperado...
En el condicional, primero se "pregunta" si el array `$zooms` (espero que sea un array, puedes preguntar al inicio con `is_array` en caso necesario) contiene el indice 0, segundo se pregunta si en el indice 0 hay un indice 'zoom', si ambos casos se avaluan positivamente se asigna el conteo de la colección de `$zooms[0]['zoom']` a `$resultado`, si este contenido no fuera una colección tendrías otro error en ese momento...

[Documentación de la función isset](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 0):

disculpen, no estoy al tanto de como se hace, sin embargo, por lo menos en mi caso (un tanto parecido, solo que uso jquery) el problema era que al momento de traerme la informacion por base de datos, la data venia vacia, por ende ese era el error, mi consulta la cambie de ser un inner Join a un leftJoin, trayendo asi toda la informacion necesaria, espero que esta respuesta sea util para alguien mas.